# Attaching a dynamically made pdf to a email c# .net Webpages

Tags: c#, pdf, email-attachments, asp.net-webpages, webmail

I am trying to attach a pdf that is made in with NReco.PdfGenerator to a email the system sends out.

I have:-

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf");
     var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
    var pdfBytes = htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile("http://{siteName}/templates/PasswordResetEmail2.cshtml", null);
    Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
```

And this works to out put a pdf to the save pop up window.

But i need to get this onto my system email,

```
WebMail.Send(
     to: email,
     subject: "Please see attached invoice",
     body: BodyTemplate,
     isBodyHtml: true,
     filesToAttach: invoice.pdf);
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Olivier below was correct on this i just needed a few other things to make it work.

As i'm new to asp.net webpages i needed to declare a line at the top of the file first to make SMTPClient work.

```
@using System.Net.Mail;
```

Then put the smtp info in the web config.

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="host_name" port="25" userName="user name" password="password" defaultCredentials="false" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
```

Then create the email.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(WebMail.SmtpServer);
            MailMessage email1 = new MailMessage();
            email1.IsBodyHtml = true;
            email1.From = new MailAddress("from@email.com");
            email1.To.Add(new MailAddress(sendemail));
            //email1.CC.Add(new MailAddress("carboncopy@foo.bar.com"));
            email1.Body = BodyTemplate;
            email1.Subject = "Please reset your password";

            var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
            email1.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "invoice.pdf"));
            smtpClient.Send(email1);
```

Answer (score 0):

WebMail.Send() seems to only send file from the hard drive.

You may use System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient to send a MailMessage. MailMessage has a method to add an attachement from a Stream, thus a byte[] using a MemoryStream.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(WebMail.SmtpServer);
MailMessage email = new MailMessage(...);
var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
email .Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "invoice.pdf"));
smtpClient.Send(email);
```

Comment: I am not sure how to use the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient. I am making the site in asp.net web pages framework. I dont think this has the System.Net.Mail class with it. and i cant find it to attach.